# Timeout when loading files using nginx

Tags: php, azure, google-chrome, nginx, kirby

Good Morning!
Currently configuring Kirby on Azure Web Apps with nginx.

I have the following issue:
[image]
The issue: All other files cant be pulled, when using the default configuration. (Port 8080)
[image]

Whats expected? The Starter website loads as usual.
What irritates me:
The files can be loaded the following way:
ben2.azurewebsites.net/assets/js/prism.js
But not with Port 8080 included (because unsecure?)
When configuring Port 80 with redirect to 443 including key & certificate the websites doesent load completely.
FYI: The Website cant send ping packages to google.de or 8.8.8.8 but can download via apt-get. Maybe DNS Issue ?

I have used this config and adapted it to my environment.
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BillBrower/105496d435c8d82114a61908666bab5e/raw/a133cde9ac6d7ce200804c0950928dedd0f5c897/kirby.conf

Different things I have tried:
Allow unsecure content in Chrome.
Empty Cache / open in private
Use Port 443 with 80 (redirect)
chmod 777 on the wwwroot directory
made www-date the owner of the directory
allowed http content in azure
checked if port 8080 and when used ssl 443 and 80 are open/listening

Thanks in advance :slight_smile:

Comment: Why would you want to use any `:8080` URL to begin with - when `https://ben2.azurewebsites.net/assets/js/prism.js` appears to be working fine, _with_ HTTPS?

Comment: Because SSL doesent work yet. Want to try http first as test.

Comment: No idea what you mean by _"Because SSL doesent work yet"_ Your screenshot clearly shows that you requested the page `https://ben2.azurewebsites.net/` via HTTPS already.

Comment: My bad! Kirby automaticly generates the scripts to load the scripts (f.x. https://imgur.com/a/2ueT4hz). So I have to modify the nginx config to ssl (atm 8080) to change the scripts to load not over 8080 f.x. (https://ben2.azurewebsites.net/assets/js/prism.js).